# Is it necessary to explode meshes in Blender for baking?

Tags: modeling, uv, sculpting

Hi I would like to know if it is necessary to explode meshes for baking process?

I am currently sculpting  a high res character with armor, the armor is composed of different pieces and has many polygons.

Should I send my different high poly parts of the model to different layers instead of creating an exploding map?

Comment: What do you mean explode, could you elaborate? What is an exploding map?

Comment: xplosion bake describes the procedure when you try to bake complex model and want to bake a normal map or whatever map.  you should drag these elements away from each other, so that each element does not interject with another and get clean baking maps. Useful for clean results...I noticed user of Maya uses a lot. I do not if use Xnormal or create cage for every single objects.